# NSDictionary valueForKey crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-coding

How can i retrieve the key value from the below `NSMutableArray` array. The below code crashes on `isEqualToString`. However i can see the value of nsRet in the variable view window as `@\x18\xaa\x01\xc8\a` before running that statement.

```
        NSMutableArray* nsMyList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [nsMyList addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             @"valueOfKey", @"Key",
                             nil]];
        NSString *nsRet = [nsMyList valueForKey:@"Key"];
        if ([nsRet isEqualToString:@"deviceClass"])
        {
            NSLog(@"Key value:%@", nsRet);
        }
```

Can anyone here please help me get the correct value for the key?
Thanks.

Comment: Just before the `if` statement, add: `NSLog(@"nsRet class is %@", [nsRet class]);`. What do you get?

Comment: That is because `[NSArray valueForKey:]` returns an array: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html

Comment: ... and `isEqualToString:` isn't implemented by `NSArray`. So an exception is raised. If you don't catch the exception then your program will be terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you need `objectForKey:`, not `valueForKey:`. The `valueForKey:` method is for key-value programming. Moreover, the call should be on the `[nsMyList objectAtIndex:0]`, like this:

```
NSString *nsRet = [[nsMyList objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Key"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You've stored the `NSDictionary` in an array.  The correct access based on your code would be:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [nsMyList objectAtIndex:0];
nsret = [dict valueForKey:@"Key"];
```

Comment: At this point, you should replace `valueForKey` with `objectForKey:`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to get the `valueForKey:` on an NSMutableArray rather than on the dictionary.

What you want is:

```
[[nsMyList objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"Key"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit lost.

In order to access the dictionary you just create you need to obtain the first element in the `NSMutableArray` and then the dictionary.

It will be something like this:

```
NSString *nsRet = [nsMyList[0] objectForKey:@"Key"]
```

I think it can solve it.